# Scan Failed in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hp, scanner

I've recently upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 LTS through the Update Manager. Since then, while the 'Document Scanner' is launched, it detects the HP scanner (Laser Jet Pro MFP M130nw, 3-in-1). But, when the Scan is launched, 'Failed to scan, unable to connect to server' message displays. The Printer works, but not the Scanner. What could be wrong? Thanks for your help.'
EDIT: I've tried 'sudo apt purge ippusbxd' as recommended by xenopeek in this [thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=329760) but the problem persists.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117497/discussion-on-question-by-kamyogi-scan-failed-in-20-04).

Comment: I solved my problem with this https://www.edoardovignati.it/how-to-install-hplip-on-ubuntu-20-04/